# Find separate REST API Key & MAP SDK Key for Android - mapmyindia API

Tags: android, api, rest, sdk, key

On the mapmyindia (map my India) API console, under "Credentials" tab of the Default Project, a default (and single) key is present "REST / Map SDK Key". In the sample code to implement Auto Suggest API (on Android), a different REST API Key & MAP SDK Key is required.

Not able to locate the different keys for REST API & MAP SDK.

Kindly help; in case I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buddy just paste that key in both the section.

```
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setRestAPIKey(firstKey1);
    MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setMapSDKKey(firstKey1);
    MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setAtlasGrantType("client_credentials");
    MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setAtlasClientId(firstKey2);
    MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setAtlasClientSecret(firstKey3);
```